# How to get json response in React from Laravel?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, guzzle

I consume an API with Laravel (with guzzle) because it's cannot be done with the client-side script (React), because the owner of the API told me that.

this is my function in the `HomeController` :

```
public function searchLocation(Request $request) {
    $client = new Client();
    $city_name = $request->route('city_name');
    $res = $client->get('https://www.example.com/search.php?lang=en&texto='.$city_name);

    $statut = $res->getStatusCode();
    $location_data = $res->getBody();

    return view('location-list')->with('location_data', json_decode($location_data, true));
}
```

I want to reconstruct the response Data with **Laravel** to send it to **React** to avoid CORS POLICY from Origin localhost:3000 (React).

How can I do that?

Comment: don't return view use return response()->json($location_data);

Comment: I already used that

Comment: 'already used' what was the response?

Comment: The same results bro